# Intercept The Ok button Clic of FragmentDialog in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

In my App, I use a FragmentDialog.

When I clic OK, it performs action and go back to MainActivity.
I can't find a way in the MainActivity to detect that user has clicked Ok in FragmentDialog.

In the Onclick Method of the fragmentDialog, I tried :

```
getActivity().setResult(PULISHED);
```

or

```
onActivityResult(CODE1, CODE2, null);
```

but in the MainActivity, I don't see it goes through the onActivityResult method...

Is there a way to intercept it???

Comment: You need to add `OnClickListener()` to OK (positive) button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onAttach` method

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        parentActivity = ((YourActivity)activity);
    }
```

and in your Activity create method `onDialogClicked()` and then set `OnClickListener` for OK button like

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        parentActivity.onDialogClicked();

    }
};);
```